# facebook login timeout in ionic 3

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Is there any way to make login timeout facebook native ionic? Thank you, here is my code.

```
fblogin() {
    this.facebook.login(['email', 'public_profile']).then((response: FacebookLoginResponse) => {
      this.facebook.api('me?fields=id,name,email', [])
      .then(profile => {
        this.model.id=profile.id;
        this.model.email=profile.email;
        this.model.username=profile.name;
      })
      .catch(err =>{ 
        alert(err);
      });
    });
  }
```

i have add catch, but the alert not showing. Thank you

Comment: maybe it is the outer promise? tried adding catch to that?

Comment: can you give me an example? @SurajRao

Comment: set the catch to the `login` promise and try